# When I open the game after I have minimized it, I first show a "Cached" screen (Unity game)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a game in which you can change the background. and for example, if I open a game, switch for example from a green background to purple, then collapse the game and then open (android), then when opening, the old background will appear for 1-2 frames first, and then a new one will load, despite the fact that this applies not only to the background, but also if some window was opened in the game, it will also not be visible
(screen 1 - 1-2 frame screen )

(screen 2 - what i should see when reopen the app and what i see after 1st sxcreen was shown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MhUd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSigR.png)

i tried set some settings in manifest, but it didnt work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.